# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_get()

Tags: 7, drush

I'm trying to get Drupal to work inside an Alpine Linux docker container but for some reason `drush` can't be used to manage the website. The website itselfactually works fine, drush just can't bootstrap.

Here's the pertinent information:

```
 /var/www/html # drush core-status
 Drupal version         :  7.56                        
 Site URI               :  http://default              
 Database driver        :  mysql                       
 Database hostname      :  vlp-dcimysql01.dhe.duke.edu 
 Database port          :                              
 Database username      :  tmp_drupal                  
 Database name          :  tmp_drupal                  
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php7/php.ini           
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                       
 Drush script           :  /usr/bin/drush              
 Drush version          :  8.1.14                      
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                        
 Drush configuration    :                              
 Drush alias files      :                              
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/html               
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php  
 Site path              :  sites/default               

/var/www/html # drush wd-show
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in /var/www/html/includes/module.inc:754
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/includes/module.inc(954): module_implements('system_theme_in...')
#1 /var/www/html/modules/system/system.module(2511): module_invoke_all('system_theme_in...')
#2 /var/www/html/includes/theme.inc(798): _system_rebuild_theme_data()
#3 /var/www/html/includes/theme.maintenance.inc(57): list_themes()
#4 /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc(2872): _drupal_maintenance_theme()
#5 /var/www/html/includes/errors.inc(179): drupal_maintenance_theme()
#6 /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc(2609): _drupal_log_error(Array, true)
#7 [internal function]: _drupal_exception_handler(Object(Error))
#8 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/includes/module.inc on line 754
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                                                                     [error]
Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in /var/www/html/includes/module.inc:754
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/includes/module.inc(954): module_implements('system_theme_in...')
#1 /var/www/html/modules/system/system.module(2511): module_invoke_all('system_theme_in...')
#2 /var/www/html/includes/theme.inc(798): _system_rebuild_theme_data()
#3 /var/www/html/includes/theme.maintenance.inc(57): list_themes()
#4 /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc(2872): _drupal_maintenance_theme()
#5 /var/www/html/includes/errors.inc(179): drupal_maintenance_theme()
#6 /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc(2609): _drupal_log_error(Array, true)
#7 [internal function]: _drupal_exception_handler(Object(Error))
#8 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/includes/module.inc, line 754
```

As stated before, the platform is Alpine Linux, PHP is 7.1.9

I can add more if anything is unclear. I've checked the PHP logs but they just produce the above output. I'm open to there just being a module/extension missing, but I'm not entirely sure how to figure that out if it doesn't ever tell me "undefined function extensionFunctionX" or something like that. The above undefined function appears to be a Drupal core function.

Note that the website works, so it's communicating with the database without issue, I can also do a `SHOW TABLES` in MySQL and see the Drupal installer's tables were created.

Comment: @kenorb Tried `drush cc all` and it just cleared the `drush` cache out. We're planning on using `redis` eventually, but haven't progressed that far into the install yet.

Comment: Does `drush sql-connect` returns the right credentials? If so, can you run: `$(drush sql-connect)` in shell?

Comment: I'm now thinking the issue is with my understanding of `drush`. The "fix" seems to be installing the `mysql` client program. [See here](https://dpaste.de/SVZ9) where it immediately started working once I added those packages. Is there a less install-heavy way of fixing this problem? Why would installing the client program matter? Shouldn't `drush` use the PDO MySQL extensions?

Comment: Installing db client matter, because drush is using the command when connecting to the database. However I'm not sure why it's needed for `wd-show` command. You can suggest some improvements at [GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues).

Answer (score 1):

In my case (moving production website to fresh server) memcached was enabled in settings.php, PHP daemon was installed and running on server, but no PHP extension was installed

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because your Drupal is not correctly bootstrapped. Normally, you should see the following lines when running `drush status`:

```
Database                        :  Connected                                                      
Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
```

So you should double check your database credentials in your settings file whether they're pointing to the right database and host (it's accessible from your command-line), your MySQL client command is installed and present (for example, with `apk add mariadb-client`) and your MySQL server is up-and-running.

You can check your database connection via `drush sql-connect` command. If that's correct, try to connect to the database by running `$(drush sql-connect)` in your shell.

In case of problems, try to clear Drush caches by using `drush cc drush` first.

If your website works fine, double check how you load your database credentials. Sometimes, people are using `if` or `switch`/`case` statements for different environments based on the host and forgot about the command-line interface which is not included.

Comment: Yeah like I was saying, the website works, so it's communicating with the database without issue, I can also do a `SHOW TABLES;` in MySQL and see the drupal installer's tables were created.

Comment: Website and command-line can work differently, they can use different PHP configuration. You need to make sure `drush` has access to the right database credentials. Please double check the answer whether you missed anything. Make sure `mysql` command is available in your shell. When you checked something, please re-edit your question to clarify what you've done so far. E.g. what's the output of: `$(drush sql-connect)` shell command.